# AngularJS: How can I bind an object with properties?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a model that looks like this:

```
var mymodel = {
   name: {
      en: 'Ten',
      es: 'Diez',
      fr: 'Dix'
   }
};
```

And a view that looks like:

```
   <section ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="findOne()">
    <form ng-submit="update()">
        <div ng-repeat="(language, string) in mymodel.name">
            <label>Name ({{language | uppercase}}):</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="mymodel.name[language]">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <pre>{{mymodel}}</pre>
    </form>
   </section>
```

When I modify the value of the textboxes, the object inside pre also changes as expected.

However, when I submit the form, the controller sends the initial values to the backend, instead of the modified ones.

The client controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('mymodule').controller('MyController', [..., function(...){
    ...
    $scope.update = function() {
       var mymodel = $scope.mymodel;
       console.log(mymodel.name);
       console.log(mymodel);
       mymodel.$update(function() {
          ...
          //Does not work as expected. Sends initial data instead of updates.
       });
    };
    ...
    $scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.mymodel = MyFactory.get({ 
            id: $stateParams.id
        });
    };
    ...
}]);
```

For examlpe, if I type in the following strings: "Fifty", "Cincuenta", "Cinquante", and click "Update", the first console.log(mymodel.name) outputs the new values:

```
Object {
    es: "Fifty", 
    en: "Cincuenta",
    fr: "Cinquante"
}
```

But the second console.log(mymodel) outputs the initial values instead:

```
Resource {
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    ...
    name: Object
       en: "Ten",
       es: "Diez",
       fr: "Dix"
    ...
}
```

The result is that the entry does not get updated in the backend.

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for your answers, I have found the error. The problem was somehow created by a plugin for interationalization in Mongoose ODM. When extending the properties of the response using lowdash, something (I have not found what exactly is yet) prevented the document from being updated, and returned the original values.

Im sorry, this had nothing to do with Angular, I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: `ng-repeat="(language, string) in mymodel"` should be `ng-repeat="(language, string) in mymodel.name"`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo while cleaning up the post, the original code was ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a plunk with your code. Also i added file `data.json` which is used to get data with `ngResource`, but instead of `id` i use `filename` the code will to be more similar with yours. Data is returned great. View is updated.
Then i try to emit data saving (press `Update` button) just for see `console.log`s. Data is written in both `console.log`s the same updated:

```
console.log(mymodel.name);
```

returns:

```
Object {en: "a", es: "a", fr: "a"}
```

And

```
console.log(mymodel);
```

returns

```
Resource {
  $promise: Object
  $resolved: true
  name: Object {
    en: "a"
    es: "a"
    fr: "a"
  }
```

I think that everything must be working fine.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6AzIsQ2vfsKZGR9RERwL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you are binding to `my model.name[language]` not what you are using in the hg-repeat to iterate. The easiest solution is to change your model (if possible) to use a structure similar to `names: [{‘lang’:’es’,’value’:’Diez’},{‘lang’:’en’,’value’:’Ten’}]`. Then you can use a standard `ng-repeat=“name in model.names”` and then bind with `ng-model=“name.value”`

If you are stuck to that model, you could try `var mymodel = angular.copy($scope.mymodel);` first to see if it makes a difference. If you make up a plunker or jsfiddle that mimics your example, it could be easier to debug a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the same example hardcoding the `ng-repeat` div (using three pairs of label/input) and still does not work. Ill try to make up a plunker, but Im not sure if Ill be able to mimic the promise returned as a Resource, which I guess has something to do with this.